# Global variables defined in Header. Other function call can see its changes

Tags: c++, variables, global, share

I have one .h file and two .cpp files:

global_var.h    fun.cpp    main.cpp

The details are shown below:

global_var.h:

```
    extern int a;
    void fun();
```

fun.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "global_var.h"
    
    
    void fun()
    {
            int a = 10;
            std::cout << "Print out in  fun() " <<  a << std::endl;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "global_var.h"
    
    int main()
    {
            int a;
            fun();
            std::cout << "Print out in main: " <<  a << std::endl;
    
            return 0;
    }
```

and also a makefile:

```
    ALL = main.o fun.o
    Target = main
    CC = g++
    
    $(Target): $(ALL)
            $(CC)  -o $(Target) $(ALL)
            
    
   
    clean:
            rm *.o
```

The output of the code is :

```
    Print out in  fun() 10
    Print out in main: 0
```

In the main function, the call to fun() modifies a as 10, and then in main it prints out again a. I thought the change of a by fun() can also be seen in main, so the output I am expectiing is :

```
    Print out in  fun() 10
    Print out in main: 10
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

My ultimate goal is to have a strucutre like below:

global_var.h
// defines (or declares. Please correct me if I used wrong terminology) all variables to be shared to all functions defined below .

func1.h   func1.cpp
// include global_var.h, define func1 which can use or modifies variables in global_var.h

func2.h   func2.cpp
// include global_var.h, define func2 which can use or modifies variables in global_var.h

.......

main.cpp
//include all .h file above. function calls here can see the modification to variables introduced by other function calls.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag this question with the language you are asking about.

Comment: `int a = 10;` inside your function is shadowing the global variable. Did you mean `a = 10;` ? And in any case, your design looks like a bad idea.

Comment: You say that you define a global variable in header (which you should not...) but I only see it declared there (good). Where do you define that global `a`? Maybe you need to provide a [mre] to show that.

Comment: @pptaszni I tried taking away the 'int'. The complier then  complains as " undefined reference a to 'a'.  By the way, can you explain a little more about the good design to achieve this ? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think a global variable is a good idea? It might seem convenient now but it can be a pain later. See [what are the pros and cons of global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-in-use-of-global-variables). TLDR there are downsides.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined a global variable. You have declared one, and then in two different places defined local variables that have the same name. N.b. your program has undefined behaviour, because you use the value of `main`'s `a` without initialising it.

Did you mean to do this instead?

fun.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "global_var.h"

int a; // definition at namespace scope.

void fun()
{
        a = 10; // assignment, not definition with initialiser
        std::cout << "Print out in  fun() " <<  a << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "global_var.h"

int main()
{
        // a is declared in the header, don't declare it again
        fun();
        std::cout << "Print out in main: " <<  a << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

However, my advice about global, mutable state is: *don't*. As your program grows in size, you will find it harder and harder to reason about what any individual part does, because you can't track what state it reads and writes.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. If I have to have variables which are to be shared by other functions, how do I do that ?

Comment: @pvasbob Then define a `class`. The shared variables would then need to become (`private`) member variables, and the functions (that use those member variables) would become member functions.

Comment: @pvasbob you pass a reference as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your header does

```
 extern int a;
```

is not (contrary to your description) a definition of `a`.   It is a *declaration* of `a`.    Although all variable definitions are a (type of) declaration, not all declarations of variables are definitions.

There is no definition of that `a` in any of your source files.

In comparison, `main()` and `fun()` both *define* a variable, local to their respective function block, named `a`.   So the `a` in `main()` is a different `a` from the one in `fun()`.   Furthermore, both of those `a`s are different from the `a` that is declared in the header.    Some people would say that the `a`s in the functions *shadow* the `a` declared in the header  (which means that, in both functions, the usage of `a` after the definition in each function refers to the local `a`, not the one declared in the header).

Your program never uses the variable `a` that is declared in the header.   Because of that, your program successfully builds (although the variable in the header is declared, it is not used anywhere, so does not need to be defined).

If we were to change one (and only one) of your source files to add another function

```
void fun2()
{
        a = 10;
        std::cout << "Print out in  fun2() " <<  a << std::endl;
}
```

This `fun2()` is works differently from your `fun()` because the `int` preceding `a = 10` is removed.   This is a small change (about three deleted characters) but the effect is significant;

- The usage of `a` in `fun2()` DOES assign a value to the variable `a` declared in the header.
- Because the variable declared in the header is used, it must be defined.
- If it is *not* defined then, with most toolchains, your program will compile (in the sense of converting .cpp files to objects) but will not *link*  (i.e. an executable will not be produced from the object files, and without an executable your program cannot be run).

If you want `fun2()` to be called, then you may add a call of it somewhere  (e.g. if you define `fun2()` in main.cpp, above `main()`, call it from `main()`).

To make our modified program build successfully, we now need to define that pesky `a`.   That must be done in one (and ONLY one) of your source files, after `#include`ing the header (and outside any function), a line like

```
  int a;     // alternatively   int a = 42; to initialise to non-zero
```

Note that, if you add this to more than one source file, you break the one-definition rule (which, practically, usually means your program will not link, due to a symbol defined multiple times).

But, unless you modify `fun()` and `main()` appropriately, neither of them refer to the `a` declared in the header.